# 24 Hour price change Mean

Tags: cryptography

If a currency price is showing ABC per coin and its price % is +X% or -X% then this reference is taken from which last price i.e. which point of time the price is taken

Answer (score 3):

The 24h % change is the difference between the current price and the price 24 hours ago.

The current price of bitcoin is $14988 and was $14937 24h ago. So the 24h change is +0.3%, even if there was a huge spike between this period of time.

Comment: How did you get +0.3%, if the current price is $14988 and was $14937 24hr ago

Comment: @JiggyFrancis (14988-14937)/14937 * 100 = 0.34%